# Reindex or Analyze Tables on PostgreSQL after import

Tags: postgresql-performance, postgresql-12

I used PostgreSQL 9.5 on a server and I ended up migrating the data to a new server using PosgreSQL 12.

Should I perform a `REINDEX` for all tables or just `ANALYZE` for all tables?

Comment: How exactly did you "migrate" the data? If you used `pg_upgrade` or `pg_restore` then you only need to `analyze` the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I ran a pg_dump -Fc and a pg_restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use pg_dump/pg_restore, then all indexes are created during pg_restore (after the data was loaded), so there is no reason to run `reindex`.

pg_restore however, does not import any statistics, so running `analyze` directly after running `pg_restore` is a very good idea.